# calc III GRE question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I will delete this when it gets answered since most people bash on me for asking these GRE questions, but idk where else to go to for help. I just need s hint in the right direction.

Find the volume of solid in $3$-space bounded by $z=x^2-1,z=1-x^2, x+y+z=2, x-2y-2z=10$.

Here is what I have attempted, we get $x=\pm 1$ by solving the first two for $x$. So are my $x$ and $z$ limits correct or no:

$\int_{-1}^1 \int \int_{1-x^2}^{x^2+1} d z dy dx$ except I get $x$'s and not $y$'s after integrating w.r.t. $z$. Sorry, I forgot lots of my Calc III. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Deleting an answered question is definitely a sin. Why are you not going back to your calculus book and reworking examples? Have you looked at the hundreds of multiple integration problems on this site? Given the first two equations, maybe the order $dzdydx$ is a poor choice. What would be better?

Comment: $x$ should come after $z$ not $y$? I have no calculus text sadly :( yeah figured my order of integration was off. also I won't delete it then! its just people here often choose to close my questions claiming too elementary

Comment: Right. It’s the projection on the $xz$-plane you can see clearly. Edit with your revised efforts.

Comment: There are multiple free calculus texts online, including Openstax and Paul's Online Notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two surfaces define a dual parabolic cylinder whose axis is along the $y$ axis, and whose perpendicular cross section is the two parabolas $z = x^2 - 1$ and $z = 1 - x^2$ intersecting at $x = -1$ and $x = 1$.  The third and fourth plane surfaces give us the limits for $y$.  Therefore the volume integral is:

$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
V &= \displaystyle \int_{x=-1}^{1} \int_{z = x^2 -1 }^{1 - x^2} \int_{y = \frac{1}{2} x - z - 5}^{2 - x - z} dy dz dx \\
&= \displaystyle \int_{x=-1}^{1} \int_{z = x^2 -1 }^{1 - x^2} (7 - \frac{3}{2} x) dz dx \\
&= \displaystyle \int_{x=-1}^{1} (7 - \frac{3}{2} x) (2 - 2 x^2) dx \\
&=\displaystyle \int_{x=-1}^{1} (14 + 3 x^3 - 14 x^2 - 3 x ) dx \\
&= \displaystyle (14 x + \frac{3}{4} x^4 - \frac{14}{3} x^3 - \frac{3}{2} x^2) \bigg|_{-1}^{1} \\
&= \displaystyle (28 - \frac{28}{3} ) \\
&= \dfrac{56}{3} \end{split} \end{equation}$